# JavaScript table onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-table, appendchild

I'm working on creating a game where a proverb is displayed in a table.  When you click on one of the letters (or td) then it displays the letter.

I used Javascript to create the table, after removing spaces/author/etc. Here is the code I used to create the table.

```
function createRow(tableRowId, startIndex, endIndex) {
    var row = document.getElementById(tableRowId);
    var index = startIndex;

    while(index <= endIndex){
        //hints array contains the letters to be displayed
        if(hints[index] != undefined){
            var newCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            var newText = document.createTextNode(hints[index]);
            newCell.appendChild(newText);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
        index++;
}
```

The problem I have is that onclick wont work with the td that were just created.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
cells.onclick = function (){
    cells.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

I must be missing a step or something, maybe some small error in my code.  Maybe there is a better way of doing this.  All the source can be found here. http://wikisend.com/download/831324/lab4.zip

Comment: Can you setup a working http://jsfiddle.net demo? Also, try to take the *jQuery!* "answers" with a grain of salt. You can easily do this without a bulky script library.

Comment: Hint: Think *delegate*, as in *delegate a click from a parent* like the `table` and utilize [`el.addEventListener('click', function(e){...})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to attach the `click` handler. Note, IE8 and lower require the alternate `el.attachEvent('onclick', function(e){...})`. The MDN site shows how to handle that.

Comment: .addEventListener() is a good solution, but in the simple demo on MDN it makes it so if anywhere in the table is clicked, the function is run.  I need it so only one cell is changed at a time.

Comment: It gets a lot easier if you eschew browsers which do not support `document.querySelectorAll`. Anyhow, that's beside the point about `addEventListener()`. See my answer and I'll edit in something for the related cells updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll update with a method to toggle the highlight to only one cell.

**EDIT**

Ok, here is a method to remove the `blue` class and add it to the one which was clicked:

```
// Remember el.attachEvent('onclick', ...) for IE8 and lower
base.addEventListener('click', function delegate(e){
    var cells = tbody.getElementsByClassName('blue'),
        i = 0,
        cell;

    while (cell = cells[i++]) {
        cell.className = cell.className.replace(/\bblue\b/g, '');
    }

    e.target.className += ' blue';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwgyK/1/

This uses `el.getElementsByClassName()`, which is supported by most modern browsers and IE9 and greater. An alternative, of course, could be to do another `tbody.getElementsByTagName('td')`, which is universally supported.

**EDIT 2**

Note, I noticed sometimes it's possible not to click a `TD`, so we should first check for that and ignore the click on `table` if it's not a `td`:

```
base.addEventListener('click', function delegate(e){
    var cells = tbody.getElementsByClassName('blue'),
        i = 0,
        cell;

    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'td') {
        while (cell = cells[i++]) {
            cell.className = cell.className.replace(/\bblue\b/g, '');
        }

        e.target.className += ' blue';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwgyK/2/

**HTML**

```
<table id="base">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var base = document.getElementById('base'),
    tbody = base.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
    numrows = 30,
    numcols = 10,
    col = 0,
    row = "<tr>{row}</tr>",
    rows = "",
    cell = "<td>{cell}</td>",
    cells = "";

// Remember el.attachEvent('onclick', ...) for IE8 and lower
base.addEventListener('click', function delegate(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});

while (numrows--) {
    cells = "";
    col = 0;

    while (col++ < numcols) {
        cells += cell.replace('{cell}', col);
    }

    rows += row.replace('{row}', cells);
}

tbody.innerHTML = rows;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwgyK/

Comment: Wow this looks great in jsfiddle.  I'm obviously new to javascript though, your code is a bit over my head haha.  Is each line in the beginning declared as a variable? Doesn't the while loop need a condition or does it just stop when numrows == 0?

Comment: Yes; declaring all of your variables with `var` is almost always preferable to not doing so (which creates global variables otherwise, which are discouraged in general). I use a comma syntax and each on a new line because I think it's easy to scan, instead of all on one line or a bunch of unnecessary `var`s scattered everywhere. To your second question, if `while (condition)`, that will stop once the `condition` evaluates to false(y). I think it's cleaner than unwieldy `for` loops, if you're careful. I updated my answer as well with the adjustment I mentioned.

Comment: So what would be an advantage or using getElementsByClass instead of getElementsByTag, since the latter is universally supported?  Also in the addEventListener function you use a parameter "e" but I'm not quite sure where that function is called.

Comment: Not much. If you were to decide you don't care about IE8 or lower, you could (and probably should) use `document.querySelectorAll('#base tbody td.blue')` instead (using my markup and classing for example); it's much more elegant. Note, I did something a lot like this [in this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/userdude/FEjKC/2/) for another question the other day. You can see how jQuery can handle it relatively easy, but learn the full DOM/vanilla methods too. And `e` is from the event, whereby it gets the `event` object that's passed into the handler. `e.target` is the element that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I solved the problem I believe by putting the addEventListener in an existing function that creates the table.  Since the getElementsByTagName was outside the function that created the table the list was null.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: No problem. I added a check on the `e.target.nodeName` as well, which I describe why in the answer edit.

Comment: Also note you can only select one answer as the correct (checkmarked) answer. You can upvote more than one, though.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote haha, sorry :( This assignment still needs a lot of work though, changing the color is only one part.  I'm trying to display the letter they click in an answer field, is there anyway to get the letter when they click it?

Comment: `cell.innerHTML`, `e.target.firstChild.nodeValue`, or `cell.innerText` (the latter is a little newer than the others). The first is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery here instead of straight js. My bet is that your listener for the click event is only bound to the items that are present when you bind it (the onclick function). If you set up a listener through jQuery, then it will fire even on components that are dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jQuery?

$(document).on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    cells.style.backgroundColor = "white";
});

I am not sure, but I believe that you'll have to explicitly attach the click function to the newly added cell if you're not using a framework. It will probably be simplest to create the function separately

```
function onClickHandler (){
    cells.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Attach the function to the cells on init

```
cells.onclick = onClickHandler;
```

and then attach it to the every element upon creation

```
newCell.onclick = onClickHandler;
```

Not sure if there's a more straight forward solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, actually if you try to alert the type of cells, you will get the answer why the the click is not triggered.

In this case, `cells` is an `NodeList` object, which is a array of `HTMLTableCellElement`.

you should iterate the cells and add onclick event like following:

```
for(var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
     cells[i].onclick = function () {
         cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
     }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty close but it still doesn't work.  You are correct that each cell is a NodeList object, which is probably why onclick is being a pain.

Comment: you can add a debug point such as `alert(1)` in the onclick function to make sure whether the click function is triggered. sorry,actually ` cells.style.backgroundColor = "white";` should be ` cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";` consistently.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the cells[i] I added and tried to put an alert(1) but no alert was thrown :p

Comment: The problem is about the DOM render, I downloaded your codes, you can alert the length of the cells under line 124 `var test = cells.length;`, you will find the browser will alert "0", that is because when those javascript codes are execute, the table in the html are not rendered yet.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks for doing that, I was guessing that is the problem but I did not have a good solution.  Should I address the problem from a different angle or try and get this to work?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I put the getElementsByTagName inside the function that created the table "createTable" and the onclick worked! Thanks for helping me though the problem

Comment: I get a     cells[index].style.backgroundColor = 'white';   is undefined error

Comment: using this.style fixes the problem